# Column doesnt exist error - Sharepoint Deployment

Tags: timer-jobs

I am getting an error while deploying a project to the Timer Jobs.  It keeps shooting me an error that says "Column does not exist", when I go to my list and my code, there is no such variable or column as what they are describing.  Is there anything that I should troubleshoot to find a solution?

Here is a bit of my stack Trace:

> 01/03/2012 13:04:31.72    OWSTIMER.EXE (0x09DC)
>     0x0A30  SharePoint Foundation           Timer
>     6398    Critical    The Execute method of job definition
>   New_Phonebook.TimeJob (ID 20b70727-9f93-4b5c-9341-2f2d34d65d89) threw
>   an exception. More information is included below.  **Column
>   'PhoneBook' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another
>   user.**   c656785a-8633-49e0-9d25-5717d2131286 01/03/2012 13:04:31.72
>     OWSTIMER.EXE (0x09DC)                       0x0A30  SharePoint Foundation
>     Timer                           72ae    Unexpected  Exception stack trace:
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetField(String strName,
>   Boolean bThrowException)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.SetValue(String strName, Object value,
>   SPField field, Boolean protectFields, Boolean skipValidation)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.set_Item(String fieldName, Object
>   value)     at New_Phonebook.TimeJob.Execute(Guid contentDbId)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvokeInternal.Invoke(SPJobDefinition
>   jd, Guid targetInstanceId, Boolean isTimerService, Int32&
>   result)   c656785a-8633-49e0-9d25-5717d2131286

Comment: Please, provide your particular code and the exact error message.

Comment: Column 'X' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.                                                                                                   There isn't any code that has X in it, thats why I am confused

Comment: What gives you the error? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: This is the error given when ran on the SharePoint 2010 Central Admin -> Job History page

Comment: It would be helpful, if we could see your code and the line where you are getting this error.

Comment: Something is wrong in the New_Phonebook.TimeJob.Execute method. If we could see the code, we could advise something. P.S. And please, the next time, if you're providing additional details, edit your question instead of adding new answer. There is an `edit` link right under the question.

Comment: Yeah, I went ahead and edited the stack trace into the question. Is PhoneBook a default SharePoint 2010 field?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a namespace called `New_PhoneBook` with a class within it called `TimeJob`. The error is coming from the `Execute` method.

The code you're looking for within that method is the part that changes the value of a list item and updates it. For example:

```
item["PhoneBook"] = "value";
// or
item[internalName] = "value";

// and

item.Update();
// or
item.SystemUpdate();
```

If the name of the field is unfamiliar, then this call may well be in a `for` loop on a list's fields, and the item may be the result of an earlier query that does not include that field.

Answer (score 0):

Is "PhoneBook" an alias for a another column like "Title"?  Did you mean "Phone Book" instead of "PhoneBook"?  Somewhere in your code you are referencing a column called "PhoneBook" - that is why you are getting an error on .GetField( fieldname,..)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you change/update your column name what sharepoint does it update the column display name only and the internal name remain same.

To get the correct col name always do the below:

1. Go to List Settings Page and Click on the Column you want to use in code

[image]

2. Copy the column name from the URL

[image]